# Get raw text from ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, local-storage

I am using ajax to get a file from the server which is an array of strings in JSON format.
When I do the ajax request as below, jQuery automatically parses the JSON string into an array.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "modules.php",
    success: function (data) {
                //data is an array object not text
            }
    });
```

However I would like to save the data to the localStorage, which can only save strings.
Rather than convert the array (data) back to a string, I'd rather stop jQuery from automatically parsing the JSON string, save the text and then parse the JSON myself.
More like:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "modules.php",
    success: function (data) {
                //jQuery hasn't parsed the JSON already, and data is a string.
                localStorage.setItem("modules", data);
                var parsedData = $.parseJSON(data);
                //use the array
            }
    });
```

Comment: Actually...JSON is a String. It is not an object. You can save a JSON String to localStorage.

Comment: Have you tried setting the `dataType` in the ajax call to `text`?

Comment: Ohgodwhy, I know, the data object is an array object, the modules.php returns a JSON string, which is parsed by jQuery into an Array before I can save it to localStorage.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy JSON is a string, but the data you get from JQuery is not.

Answer (score 9):

According to the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

```
success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR)
```

the XHR object contains the response text:

```
jqXHR.responseText
```

Comment: But jQuery will still parse the response into an array (the data arguement)? Is there a way to avoid parsing it twice?

Comment: Or I could save the reponse using the `jqXHR.responseText` and use the `data` array instead of parsing myself?

Comment: As @sellmeadog suggested above, setting `dataType` to text should give you the actual responseText in the `data` argument.

Comment: the jqXHR object is deprecated in jQuery 1.8.

Answer (score 5):

You need to bypass jQuery MIME type verification by using the `dataType` attribute :

```
$.ajax({
    url: "modules.php",
    success: function (data) {
        //data is an array object not text
    },
    dataType: "html"
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Per the documentation, "jQuery will try to infer [the data type] based on the MIME type of the response" if no `dataType` is specified in the ajax call.

On a per call basis, you can add the `dataType` to the call body as shown by AsKaiser (but I would use `text` instead of `html`). If you always want plain text returned for every ajax call, you can use jQuery's [`$.ajaxSetup()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup).

Answer (score 0):

Don't use JQuery! You could use plain JavaScript for this request. Have you tried http://www.w3schools.com/ajax? See Request and Response. You'll use slightly more code, but it'll be faster, and give you the response directly. Here's a wrapper I have written:

```
function AJAX(url, success, async) {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest;
    } else {
        // IE6 and IE5 (unnecessary)
        var request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHttp");
    }
    if (async) request.onReadyStateChange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
            success(request.status, request.responseText);
        }
    };
    request.open("GET", url, async);
    request.send();
    if (!async) success(request.status, request.responseText);
}
```

This function takes the URL as a string, the success function as a function accepting `(status code, response string)`, and whether it is asynchronous as a Boolean.